# azure functions url rewriting to fetch blobs from storage account

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've been struggling to fetch blobs from storage account with azure functions (v4).

I've a function (HTTPTrigger) to do this with below `function.json`.

```
{
    "bindings": [
      {
        "authLevel": "anonymous",
        "route": "",
        "type": "httpTrigger",
        "direction": "in",
        "name": "req",
        "methods": [
          "get"
        ]
      },
      {
        "type": "http",
        "direction": "out",
        "name": "res"
      }
    ]
  }
```

And `host.json` in the root directory is below:

```
"extensions": { 
  "http": { 
    "routePrefix": "" 
  } 
}
```

No matter whatever I do, I can't access `blobs` (I wrote some golang code to authenticate with storage account to fetch blobs). The go binary I built works fine in standalone mode.

Now my question is, I don't want `/api/<function-name>` or `<function-name>` in the url to be passed by customer. I've `index.html` files in storage account so as to guide my users to download blobs.

Unfortunately, using `/api/*` or `function-name` is not an option for me.

I tried various combinations & went through different questions but always got `404` error while accessing the blob path.

```
Executed HTTP request: {
 requestId: "825defcf-bb0f-4260-8eb1-04670225e176",
 identities: "",
  status: "404",
}
```

I don't even know if this is really supported or possible.

Answer (score 1):

The Azure Function "[HTTPtrigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?pivots=programming-language-csharp&tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process%2Cfunctionsv2)" only has invocation Url to trigger the function.
As mentioned you can remove or modify the "api" prefix using the "routePrefix" option in the "host.json", but there's no way to ajust the trigger Url.

The only way to rewrite the url is with Azure API management. (See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/rewrite-uri-policy))

Comment: Thanks Philip. Sorry to reply this late. I ended up using APIM for this as it seemed to be a good fit.